# How to calculate area under the curve (AUC) in several data series?

Tags: r, plot, auc

I have the data of blood parameters from around 400 patients and from each patient I collected the parameter on 30 consecutive days. So each patient has around 30 values.

It looks like this:
[image: image of dataset]

So from these data I want to calculate the area under the curve for each patient.

As I see probably the "pROC" package could help me with this. But what is the fastest method to calculate the AUC for each patient? I want to avoid to calculate it for each patient manually.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, questions should be reproducible to make it easier to help you. Please don’t use images of code or data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Check out SO guidance [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Hi Alexander. This would be straightforward to do with `lapply` or a mapping function from the tidyverse. However, without a reproducible example of your data frame, it won't be possible to help you. Please edit your question.